# Does AMQP have a default queue to send messages that don't match any bindings in the exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have a producer that will produce to an exchange for a given key. Sometimes the key may not be have a binding yet, so I'd like the message to go to a default queue. Is there any way to specify for an exchange where to put a message if there are no matching bindings?

Does AMQP, or RabbitMQ, offer any such ability for a default queue for non-matching messages? Is there a pattern for this that I could exploit if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [Alternate Exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) is what you are looking for.